# How do you represent an application in UML?

Tags: uml

Is it as simple as just a square or rectangle with the application name in the center?

Comment: Depends on what do you want to represent and what diagram are you using. For instance, in a use case diagram, an external application can be expressed as an actor, sending or receiving data from your use cases. In a sequence diagram, you external application can be draw as a boundary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by application, you mean an other (external) system which interact with your system (application) then it is an actor. You can stereotype that actor as application and in some software gives it a specialized icon (square or whatever). Unfortunately all UML softwares are very poor in representation so sometimes it's better to use a graphics software to draw nice UML diagrams.

Comment: Can the answer be improved, maybe by giving a practical example? Imagine you have 2 workstations with a specific role, on each run 3 applications with specific purposes and they are using some software components. How would the deployment view look like? Is the symbol for the process or application (however you like to name a .exe...) the same as for a software component (e.g. C# assembly)? Would the application "component" then have "dependencies" on the "real" components?
~~ Sometimes abstraction is good but sometimes you just want to say what you mean ;)

Answer (score 1):

I have been using UML to describer enterprise level architetures, where in a component diagram one component per application and in sequence diagrams one lifeline per application was used.

Answer (score -1):

The square or ractangle define the system not the application in UML. 
Also at the when you  prepare UML, you dont have an application. You only have a problem that belong to a system that have some actors and some process ( use cases ).

So there is no point to include application in UML.

Comment: how do you represent enterprise architectures and data flows?